# Why can one call a static method on a type parameter if Java's generics aren't reified?

Tags: java, generics

What's the point of allowing static method invocation on type parameters if Java couldn't be bothered with type reification?

```
public class a {
    interface Foo {
        static int getNum() { return 0; }
    }

    static class FooT implements Foo {
        static int getNum() { return 1; }
    }

    interface A<T extends Foo> {
        default int getFooNum() {
            return T.getNum();
        }
    }

    static class B implements A<FooT> {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A p = new B();

        // A rational being would expect this to print 1, but being the great
        // language that Java is, earthly rationality doesn't hold.
        System.out.println(p.getFooNum());
    }
}
```

Comment: Type parameters are really useful when you have, say, an `ArrayList<String>` and you want to extract an element from it. Before generics, you'd have to cast the extracted element to a String before using it. I recommend reading [Why Use Generics?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html#:~:text=Why%20Use%20Generics%3F,defining%20classes%2C%20interfaces%20and%20methods.&text=By%20using%20generics%2C%20programmers%20can,safe%20and%20easier%20to%20read.)

Comment: However, I do agree that this is strange behavior. One shouldn't be allowed to invoke static methods on type parameters at all